# Using the JS and CSS in the Assets folder with PHP in Android

Tags: php, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I am developing a web application using PHP uploaded in my server. But since it requires a number of CSS and JS files, I wonder if i could store those files in the assets folder of the android application and access the files using the php/html page which is in my server. In short, I need the external css,js files to be in the application's asset folder and the php file in my server and I need them to be displayed using webview.

If this is not possible, can anyone tell me a better way to use PHP web application in android? I am using HTML5, css3, jQuery mobile and PHP, MySQL. I am good with web designing compared to application UI design, so I am going for the HTML5 way.

Comment: you can put css or js in assets and run them by java code,but I think you can't do this by php on server